# Is there any way to delay javascript execute like this?

Tags: javascript, delay

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wait for a period of time after a function run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133947/how-to-wait-for-a-period-of-time-after-a-function-run)

here is a sample of the code:

run1();

// delay 1 sec

run2();

// delay 1 sec

run3();

Comment: Have u done any research? [Very first result](https://www.google.com/search?q=delay+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Although that "first result" does not have good in browser results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is asynchronous things in browser, which allows to prevent delays in working with it by users. You may only use timeouts and callbacks.

For your proposes you may organize something like a queue:

```
var cur = 0;
var functions = [run1, run2, run3, ...];

var next = function () {
  functions[cur]();
  cur += 1;
  if (cur == functions.length) clearInterval(interval);
};

var interval = setIntervar(next, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes! You get what i mean. Thanks Danil.

Comment: JavaScript is not and never was "asynchronous language". It is browser environment that is event-driven and asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)() function which allows you to delay x number of milliseconds before executing code.

e.g.

```
run1();

setTimeout(function() {
    run2();

    setTimeout(run3, 1000);
}, 1000);
```