# How to load and then replace that content after specific time via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, setinterval

I have a problem with ajax :

Scenario is : onclick "triggre", load content from first div of "noti.html" via ajax into "#topNoti" and after that change/replace this loaded content after specific time with second div of "noti.html" and so on until the last div content is not loaded.

```
noti.html:
  `  ....
     <div id="inq">
     <div id="div1">This is first div</div>
     <div id="div2">This is second div</div>
     <div id="div3">This is third div</div>
     <div id="div4">This is fourth div</div>
    ...
     <div id="div24">This is last div</div>

     </div>
    ...
```

'

```
#topNoti:
    <div id="topNoti"></div>
```

Thanks and regards

Currently i used :

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
var index=1;
$m=$("#inq").find("div"+index);
setInterval(function(){
$("#topNoti").load("noti.html",$m);
index=index+1;
If(index==25){ index=1; }
},10000);
});
```

But this code load all div. can anyone give me solution to load "div" one by one

I just modify my script n with this i can do what i want.
Code is:

```
 Var index=0;
 SetInterval(function(){
 $("#topNoti").load("noti.html #div"+index);
 index=index+1;
 If(index==25){index=0;}
 },2000);
```

So, can anyone improve this code...

Thanks n regards

Comment: So what is your issue? Using click handler or load() jquery method or timeout? What have you tried???

Comment: I think this exact thing is used in [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/) look at the 3rd example... it's the exact same thing

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge of jquery, so i just simply used "$('.trigger').click(function(){ $('#topNoti).load('noti.html #a');});" so it loads the first div of noti.html. But dont know how to replace it with second div content and continue this process until last div content is not replaced.

Comment: I achieved this goal with 'setTimeout' function but the drawbacks of my  setTimeout function is that for every div i have to use a separate function. And there are 26 divs present in noti.html, so 26 setTimeout functions :(

Comment: I think your problems are entirely googleable (that's why I downvoted). Just some basic things that should help:
https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+replace
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133991/1501916

Comment: @Gorge: before posting here i tried to google to find out the solution. I know how to use setTimeout function but dont know how to get content one bye one just on a single click and less setTimeout

Comment: @Anand Pilania can you post your jquery code here?

Comment: as per my suggestion you should load div based on index not Id from noti.html using this way you can use single  setTimeout function.

Comment: @RajeshKumar: i don't have jquery code to do this. Still i used "$('.trigger').click(function(){ $('#topNoti).load('noti.html #a');});"  with different setTimeout function with different times based on previous setTimeout.I checked your example, its truly nice but i can't use it according to my needs (loading div via ajax one by one). I really appreciate your suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you load the divs via AJAX every time you want to show a different one? If they're all on the same page, get it once and hide/show as requried, otherwise you're just wasting network resource for no reason

Comment: @Basic: i load them bcz they are some important notification messages. And due to the importance, i have to load them one by one. Now I did it (plz check the code) but still waiting for improved code.

Comment: So... I'm not saying you shouldn't _show_ them one by one - but why load them 25 times? Are they being updated constantly? You're downloading the page every 2 seconds for no clear reason. If they _are_ being updated constantly then there are far better approaches to doing this (like keeping track of which was the last one to load). There's a difference between downloading the page (AJAX) and showing what you downloaded (Javascript/CSS).

Comment: @Basic: sorry but i dont have deep knowledge of jquery or js. So plz can you give me a demo with code. The noti.html is updated constantly according to the new message, so i have to load it after few minutes. And there are more than 8 div. 25 is used just for demo purpose

Comment: @AnandPilania I'll see what I can do. Do you have control over whatever created `noti.html` or is it coming from someone else?

Comment: @Basic: Yes, i have control bcz this is my project. And thanks in advance

Comment: @AnandPilania do you want to load the content every time via ajax load. this is not feasible solution. as you said that your "noti.html" file is updated frequently so for this purpose I suggest you to load this file on page load / refresh of page after that display the content of this loaded info.

Comment: @AnandPilania I think this will solve your problem as your file is updated frequently so each and every time when page is loaded or get refreshed you will load Latest updated info from "noti.html"

Comment: @RajeshKumar: so please can you tell me that how can i do this (load this noti.html with refresh/load)? (With code/jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GbQzh/

```
var index = 0;
var count=$("#topNoti div").length;
$("#topNoti div").hide().eq(index).show();
setInterval(function() {
     $("#topNoti div").hide().eq(index).show();
     index = index + 1;           
     if (index == count) {
         index = 0;
      }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But @rajesh i have to load content from different html file via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do it...

```
var index=0;

function Next() {
    //Hide old div (if any)
    if(index>0) {
        document.getElementById('part'+index).style.display='none';
    }
    index++;
    document.getElementById('part'+index).style.display='block';
    if(index<4) {
        setTimeout(Next, 1000);
    }
}
```

Assuming your Divs have a numerical ordering to their Ids...

```
<div id="part0" style="display:none;">Hi</div>
<div id="part1" style="display:none;">Some</div>
<div id="part2" style="display:none;">Message</div>
<div id="part3" style="display:none;">Across</div>
<div id="part4" style="display:none;">Divs</div>
```

Comment: How to use this function to get content of div via ajax

Comment: Load all the divs in one go, then show as appropriate... Are you [unable to load content via ajax](http://api.jquery.com/load/)? If so, what exactly is the problem?